# Android UncaughtExceptionHandler not called

Tags: java, android, exception

In my Application subclass `onCreate` I'm doing this:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(final Thread thread, final Throwable ex) {
                Log.d("tag","Uncaught exception hander triggered");           
            }
        });
```

but the log statement doesn't appear in logcat.  It says `D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM` and then prints the stack trace of the exception.  Does this indicate that the thread already has an exception handler and so my default one isn't called?  If so, is there a way to do something with exceptions before the app exits?  The sources I've read seem to indicate to do what I'm doing, so I'm not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: can you share full source ?

Comment: myself work fine @nasch

Comment: @MageshPandian I cannot share the entire project.  What else would you like to see?